# Can i trigger a Google Assistant action on a Google Home from a server / raspberry pi?

Tags: raspberry-pi, actions-on-google, google-home

I recently created a custom Google Assistant action that helps me manage my personal tasks. I also have a raspberry pi that can cast voice messages to my Google Home speaker. It basically notifies me when it's time to do a specific task. The action is capable of registering if I did this task or not.
So after the voice message reminder is casted, I would like to respond to it immediately, so that I don't have to open the action myself with the default opening command (Hey Google, let me talk to 'My App').

I'm wondering if a raspberry pi is able to trigger the Google Home speaker to open an action. Or is it only possible to open an action by using the default opening command?

Comment: This sounds like over-engineering, IMHO. From the way I understand your question, you want to remotely start a conversation on a Google Home. Is something preventing you (or the user) from simply telling the Google Home, "Hey Google, talk to My App"?

Comment: I would like that the speaker could initiate the conversation based on some events